# What would be the output of the following code snippet and why?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, arithmetic-expressions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef    unsigned     int    U32;
int main() {
    U32 var     = -1;
    printf("var = %u\n", var);
    if(var != -1)
    {
        printf("\n I'm not -1\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I'm -1 and Var :%u\n", var);
    }
 }
```

Here "-1" should be converted into an `unsigned` `int` and it should be assigned to `var`. And then at the `if` condition it should not be equal to -1. But it is going into the `else` statement.

Comment: Why do you think the second `-1` won't be converted too? And the compiler warns you about a signed/unsigned comparison mismatch?

Comment: you should also get a warning about that. But it's expected that it goes on the else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that all integer constants such as `1` have a type. Given that `U32` is `unsigned int`, then:

- In the case of `U32 var = -1;` (assignment), the right operand of type `int` is converted to the type of the left operand.
- In the case of `if(var != -1)`, the `-1` operand is converted from type `int` to `unsigned int` as per *the usual arithmetic conversions*, details here: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

In both cases, a signed to unsigned conversion occurs and such a conversion is well-defined as per 6.3.1.3:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.

Meaning that in both cases above, the same unsigned value `0xFFFFFFFF` will be generated.

Comment: An explicit `U` suffix on that might make this clearer and silence a compiler warning.

Comment: @JL2210 What do you mean? `-1U` is only going to give you warnings of a different kind.

Comment: What warnings would it give?

Comment: @JL2210 Using unary minus with an unsigned operand etc.

Comment: I'm not getting any warnings even with `-Weverything` and `clang`.

Comment: @JL2210 A compiler isn't required to warn for that, though I believe some do. Static analysers most definitely do. Regardless, there is no doubt that unary minus with an unsigned operand is very fishy code.

Comment: I'm not getting anything after inserting this into my project and running `scan-build`.

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
if(var != -1)
```

the compiler needs to determine the common type of the operands. This process is named the usual arithmetic conversions.
From the C Standard (6.5.9 Equality operators)

> 4 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
>   conversions are performed....

And relative to the usual arithmetic conversions (the C Standard, 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, **then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.**

So according to the quote in the expression of the if statement the integer constant `-1` having the type int is converted to the type unsigned int that is to the type of the variable `var` because the types int and unsigned int have the same rank and the variable `var` has the type unsigned int.

As a result the condition yields false.

Answer (score -2):

An `int`, be it signed or `unsigned` is represented by a series of bits, like

> B1B2...Bn

where

> Bi ∈ {0; 1}

now, the biggest representable `unsigned` `int` looks like

```
1111...1
```

however, as a signed value, -1 is represented by

```
1111...1
```

as well

so, 1111...1 == 1111...1 is true. The conversion into `unsigned` did not change any values, it changes the way the given value is perceived. And in terms of memory representation 2^(32-1) and -1 is effectively the same dude, dressed in different clothes.

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant this is, because all that matters here is how the integer conversion is carried out. For example `(long long)-1 == (unsigned long long)-1` is always true but `(long long)-1 == (unsigned int)-1` is always false.